# Clean WSS_Logging database

Tags: 2013, database, cleanup, wss-logging

Altough the logging of my SharePoint 2013 has been completely disabled a few months ago, I still find entries from April 2015 in the db today (2015-11-12).

Checking with `Get-SPUsageDefinition` all entries are set to `False`.

How is it possible? How can I clean up these tables?

[image]

Comment: What are the retention values that returned by Get-SPUsageDefinition?  And have you checked to see if the timer jobs that clean old data are running as expected? There are two Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data ... jobs that do this.  If they are running then perhaps re-enabled usage definitions but set the retention to 1 day.

Comment: I set the retention value to 3 and run both jobs. The old data has not been removed...